# Apache RewriteRule not being triggered

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got the following setup in my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On

#1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC,QSA]

#2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^about$ /about-us [L,R=301]

#3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^catalog$ /products [L,R=301]
```

For some reason `#2` and `#3` are not being triggered.

If I disable `#1`, then `#2` and `#3` do work.

Comment: Do the #2 and #3 rule apply to real paths? As in, does about and catalog exist in the filesystem under the documentroot?

Comment: Yes, the used page names are under the document root.

Comment: change #1 to FallbackResource /index.php  <-- this directive only applies to when uri requested does not exist, if you still get the index.php loaded then your htaccess is not under the virtualhost with the documentroot you think or something else overrides them.

Comment: In any case I mean if "catalog" and "about" do they really exist?

Comment: No, the #2 and #3 rules do not apply to real paths in this situation. This was a test setup on an empty project where all routes are send through an (almost) empy index.php file. 

I was having issues with redirects in my real application so I tried to hunt down the problem using a test setup where there are effectively no invalid url's and there a no directories or files other than an .htaccess and an index.php file.